# Replace all letters in a string with an underscore and space

Tags: c++

As the title says, I am attempting to replace every letter in a string with an underscore followed by a space. For example: "hello" would be replaced with
"_ _ _ _ _". I can replace letters with just a space or just an underscore, but I am having trouble with replacing both. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have used a for loop to replace individual letters, but that is as far as I am currently.

Comment: Count how many letters are in the input string and then construct a new string with that many `"_ "` pairs.  You will need a loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think your proposed algorithm is flawed.

Comment: @WallaceMogerty Please add your code ([edit] the post). Maybe also add some examples (input; desired output) to make it clearer what exactly you want.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not sure, the requirements aren't exactly clear.  I guess it depends on how to handle spaces and whether or not there are any spaces in the string.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, actually it depends on the definition of "letter".

Comment: Do you need to add spaces here, or could you just replace all letters with underscore? Maybe handle the spaces in the output. Not the most efficient, but might be a quick solution.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks to NathanOliver for the help. Here is the code for anyone who's curious: `string test = "hello";
   string newWord = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < int(test.length()); i++)
    {
        newWord += "_ ";
    }
    cout << newWord;`

Comment: You are asking about *replacing*, which suggests modifying a string, not creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

A `regex` based solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    std::string s = "hello";
    std::regex_replace(std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), s.begin(), s.end(), std::regex("."), "_ ");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient solution, but it should be easy to understand:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string theString = "hello";
    std::string theResult = "";
    for (int count = 0; count < theString.length(); count++)
    {
        theResult += "_ ";
    }
    std::cout << theResult;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    string output;
    int size_input;

    cin>> input;
    size_input= input.size();

    for(int i=0; i<size_input; i++)
    {
        output+= "_";
        if(i!= size_input-1)
            output+= " ";
    }

    cout<< output<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

To mock you a bit more. You can't!

I mean, if you have string "hello", "replacing" it by "_ _ _ _ _ " is not just replacing, but also extending.

If you are doing some hangman game, don't replace it, keep the source word as is, having 5 characters.

Also keep around some `vector<bool> visibility;` initialized to length 5x `false`.

Where you want your "_ " is display method of word, where you display per-letter either `"_"` or the letter from string, according to `visibility[index]`, and move the position of next letter far enough to simulate some adequate space. This will later over course of game lead to display like "h e _ _ o" (notice the spaces included also between letters).

If you need this for something different, my advice may be wrong...

But generally, unless you really want to destroy the original string in memory, don't overwrite it, generate new one. Then the advice from @NathanOliver is valid. If you want to destroy original string in memory, then question is where it is stored (`char *string = "hello";` is compiled into read-only const segment, you don't want to write there) and how that memory was allocated, that decides whether you can even enlarge it enough to contain 2x more letters ("_ " pairs).

---

edit:
After checking OP profile, I see he's very likely really working on hangman game, so my guess was correct, and I do believe my answer will help him lot more in the long run.

About that "mock". I wasn't the one downvoting his question. But he was already well in negatives - that and my sarcastic nature lead me into such opener.

Anyway, I would love to hear from OP himself, if he does find it offensive, or he felt the weird sense of awkward humour of it, and understood from rest of the answer, that I tried to care and help.

So I can do a proper *facepalm*, if he's hurt. It's not fair to have fun only from oversensitive commenters :/, I can't be satisfied by that.

Comment: Why mock the user?  You can most definitely *replace* the contents of a string with the conveniently named [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).

Comment: Just an example to support @NathanOliver. A string containing "a b c " is an edge case that would replace, and not have to extend.

Comment: @NathanOliver: as `std::string` is high abstraction container, you have zero control over the implementation, thus you have no idea whether the letters were replaced in memory itself. From high level abstraction your suggestion is completely correct and valid. Yet if by accident OP wanted to erase string from memory (security reasons?), it would be invalid. OP is not mentioning `std::string`, but `string`, which can mean many things (I went for C-like character array). Why "mock"... my weird humour. So funny to see you take it so seriously, why the rest of the answer tried to be factual. :D

Comment: @Taztingo ok, you win, I overlooked that one.

Comment: Also I tried to point in answer, that from programming style it's usually better to not modify the string, but create new one (following "immutability" voluntarily). So asking for `replace` should have some good reason, otherwise the OP should rather ask how to avoid replacing/modification.